# CSS class being applied to element without that class name, any ideas?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, razor

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="tblSearchChoice" class="search-client-table">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Filter Search</strong></td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option,
                 new SelectList(Model.SearchOptions, "Value", "Text", Model.Option), "Please Select"</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="clientResults" class="searchResultsTable">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="text-align: center">ID</th>
             <th style="text-align: left">Name</th>
             <th>Address</th>
             <th>Last Delivery</th>
             <th>Next Delivery</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          @foreach (ClientDetailsViewModel client in Model.Clients)
          {
              @Html.Partial("_SearchDetailsRow", client)
          }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Nothing complicated.   I have a CSS file with a class for reach table, a "search-client-table" class, and a "searchResultsTable" class.  The problem I have is that the searchResultsTable class is being applied to BOTH tables.  The top table is getting both classes applied to it, when it should only be "search-client-table" class.  There's only one CSS file, with no duplication of the class names in the file, and the two table IDs aren't anywhere in the CSS file, they're used for Jquery purposes.  There is no other element on this page with the class name of "searchResultsTable", no other CSS files, and the Jquery doesn't have any mention of "searchResultsTable" in it, so I don't think it could be that.  I am stumped.  How is that top table getting the 2nd table's class applied to it? I'm using C#, MVC 4, Visual Studio 2012, in case that may be relevant.  Here's the relevant CSS just in case it's relevant too.

```
.search-client-table {
    background-color: #337AB7;
    border-top: 3px solid #00B5C6;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00B5C6;
}

.search-client-table td {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #337AB7;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-client-table input {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.searchResultsTable {
    border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    width: 950px;
}


.searchResultsTable th {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #00B5C6;
    color: #ffffff;
}

 .searchResultsTable tr,td {
   border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
}

.searchResultsTable td label {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
     border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
}

.searchResultsTable .email a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

    .searchResultsTable .email a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .searchResultsTable .email a:visited {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .searchResultsTable .email a:hover:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

I can't think of what could be causing this, I've tried clearing the browser cache, cleaning and rebuilding the solution.  I'm at a loss, anybody got any idea what could cause something like this, or can anyone point me in the right direction to investigate this further? Thanks.

Edit: sorry, copied the same CSS twice, instead of adding the searchResultsTable.  Added it.  I've used IE, Chrome, and Firefox, and they all do the same thing.  I'll see if I can add a fiddle, though it probably won't happen on that, whatever it is that's going on..

Edit2: added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rov9jfhj/), but it's not doing the same thing there.  I knew it wouldn't - there must be a conflict somehow somewhere in my project, but I don't see what it could be.  Another CSS file would do it, but there isn't one, there's no inline CSS that could be over riding it.  AHHH! Why is this happening? What are, theoretically, the possible reasons that something like this could happen?

## Solved!

Thanks very much to Gary McGill below who solved this one, it was really stupid, I didn't realise this CSS
    .searchResultsTable tr,td {
       border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
    }
was applying to ALL TDs.  Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: could you please share `searchResultsTable` css class?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for this and share, so that we could actually see what may cause the problem.

Comment: What you're describing isn't possible, so the cause is something else. Without a demo that demonstrates the issue, your suit is cold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration:

```
.searchResultsTable tr,td { ... }
```

applies to all `tr` elements within an element with class `searchResultsTable`, and **all** `td` elements.

I think you meant:

```
.searchResultsTable tr, .searchResultsTable td { ... }
```

Comment: Just tried this, you are 100% correct, thanks very much. I can't believe it was something as stupid as that.  You are a legend!  I would upvote you but my rep is non-existent (new member)

Comment: @ailinmcc666 You can presumably still accept the answer - and this will gain you some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, css classes with same definitions related to 
`.search-client-table` are repeated multiple times in the css. Please remove duplicate classes from css. As we know, this is not a cause for issue.

I think other css must be loading somehow which applies to second table. You can check and confirm with firebug if any other css is being loaded.

At last, if this still doesn't solve, you can always add element id into all css classes like below so that css doesn't apply to any other tables but the first table only.

```
#tblSearchChoice.search-client-table {...}
```

Comment: checked it using firebug, there is definitely on other CSS being loaded.  That's why it's so confusing!

Comment: If you have live url to this page, please paste here so that I can debug it.

Comment: I don't, sorry. It was solved by a user above, it was something really stupid that I did in the CSS.

Comment: Yes, I see that, even I am amazed, why I didn't see it.